# ASP.NET Web-API Facebook login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity-2

I'm developing an Android App with an ASP.NET Wep-API Backend. Currently i have problems with the Facebook login. I want to login the users with the FB Access Token i get by the Facebook Android SDK. Is this possible? I thought i read something about that this is possible without a workarround by directly post the token to the /signin-facebook endpoint, but i can't find that solution anymore. So here is my question: 
Is it possible to login/register to an ASP.NET Web-API directly with the facebook token? Or do i have to implement a workaround?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web API comes with OWIN which then allowing you to implement (or activate) Access token login.   You need to register to Facebook developer in order to get the app Id and secret key.

You can install in your web api project using nuget:

Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook -Version 2.1.0

More detail.. you can try follow the link [here](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/)